# Django - queryset based on list interval

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model and want to get a Queryset based on the order_by clause which is set to a time field in descending order. I don't want to return all these objects. I just want to return the objects in the list interval from start to end.

For now, I get all the objects in Queryset list and manually slice the python list (list[start:end]). The problem is that the list contains over 100k records. So it is a time consuming option.

Is there any way in which I can pass this start and end parameter to Django and it only returns the queryset list after applying that slice?

Example -

```
class DemoModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    added_time = models.DateTimeField()
    .........
```

Views:

```
queryset = DemoModel.objects.order_by('-added_time')
return queryset[start:end]
```

Here I have 100k entries in DemoModel and want to return suppose the first 1000 ie from start = 0 to end = 999

Comment: Please share the model and give an example. Right now it is unclear exactly *what* you want to achieve.

Comment: How is the interval declared? Can you just use `YourModel.objects.filter(date__range=(dt_1, dt2))`?

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: You can't apply the `filter()` on a ***sliced queryset***

Comment: Okay, is there any work aorund it ?

Comment: This is not manually slicing: querysets are lazy, so if you `return queryset[start:end]`, then you will make a query with `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0` for example.

Comment: What might however help is add a database index on `added_time`, so `added_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

> For now, I get all the objects in Queryset list and manually slice the python list (`list[start:end]`).

The slicing is *not* done at the Django/Python level. `queryset` is a `QuerySet`, not a list. `QuerySet`s are lazy, so they do not make a database query, unless you *consume* the values, for example by iterating over it. If you thus use `queryset[start:end]`, you simply constructed a *new* `QuerySet`, and if that queryset is consumed, it will query with `… LIMIT … OFFSET …`.

What probably is causing the delay is that the database needs to order all the elements by. Since there is no index, that takes a lot of time, since the database will first need to read the `added_time` of all elements, and then sort these manually.

You can boost efficiency by adding a database index:

```
class DemoModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    added_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    # …
```

and then make a migration and migrate the database.

Comment: Hi @Willem, Thanks for your response, I will try that out.